# PL/SQL package type vs schema type

Tags: oracle, plsql, package, plsqldeveloper, nested-table

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
create or replace
package MyPackage
as
    type string_list_t is table of varchar2(32767);

    function GetPrimaryKeys    ( p_table_name varchar2, p_owner varchar2 )
        return string_list_t;
end MyPackage;
/

create or replace
package body MyPackage as

function GetPrimaryKeys ( p_table_name varchar2, p_owner varchar2 )
return string_list_t
is
    pk_descr string_list_t;
begin
    select cast( multiset (
        select cols.column_name
          from all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
          where cols.table_name = p_table_name
          and cons.constraint_type = 'P'
          and cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
          and cols.owner = p_owner
          and cons.owner = p_owner
    ) as string_list_t) into pk_descr from dual; -- error refers to string_list_t

     return pk_descr;
end;

end MyPackage;
```

But it doesn't compile:

> Error(16,14): PL/SQL: ORA-00902: invalid datatype

When I define `string_list_t` outside of the package as

```
create or replace
type string_list_t is table of varchar2(32767);
```

it compiles and works as expected. What makes the difference here and how do I do it correctly with the type defined in package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to use a SQL select statement that uses the type, then it must be a SQL type. You cannot return a PL/SQL type to SQL.

Another option that might work is to create a for loop and populate the array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MyPackage as

  function GetPrimaryKeys ( p_table_name varchar2, p_owner varchar2 ) return string_list_t
  is
    pk_descr string_list_t;
    --iCounter  number:=1;
  begin

    /*------------------------------
     -       new version                 
     ------------------------------*/
    SELECT cols.column_name
      BULK COLLECT INTO pk_descr
    FROM   all_constraints cons, 
           all_cons_columns cols
    WHERE  cols.table_name = p_table_name
      AND  cons.constraint_type = 'P'
      AND  cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
      AND  cols.owner = p_owner
      AND  cons.owner = p_owner;

    /* old version */
    FOR rec in (select cols.column_name
                from   all_constraints cons, 
                       all_cons_columns cols
                where  cols.table_name = p_table_name
                  and  cons.constraint_type = 'P'
                  and cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
                  and cols.owner = p_owner
                  and cons.owner = p_owner) 
    LOOP

      pk_descr(iCounter):= rec.column_name;
      iCounter:= iCounter+1;
    END LOOP;


    RETURN pk_descr;
 END;

END MyPackage;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on what is a SQL type and what is a PL/SQL type here?

Comment: @vines -- by "SQL type" he means a type created at the schema level using CREATE TYPE; by "PL/SQL type" he means a type declare inside a PL/SQL block.  SQL statements, even those within PL/SQL blocks, cannot see PL/SQL type declarations.

Comment: @Jeff -- perhaps you could do that with a BULK COLLECT INTO instead?

Comment: @Jeff Moore, @Dave Costa: thanks a lot! `bulk collect into` is the thing, Jeff, please, update the answer or Dave — post yours, so I could mark it as the right one :)

Comment: I have updated the code example to show the bulk collect example.